# Ghostscript Error "undefined in H.S"

Tags: errors, miktex, ghostscript, yap

I downloaded a thesis proposal template. When I compile it no error appears, but to display `dvi`, I got the following error. So what is the problem and how to fix it?

```
Error: /undefined in H.S
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   PermitFileReading   --nostringval--   PermitFileWriting   --nostringval--

Execution stack:
%interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   
%stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1    
%stopped_push   1914   1   3   
%oparray_pop   1913   1   3   
%oparray_pop   1897   1   3   
%oparray_pop   1787   1   3   
%oparray_pop   --nostringval--   
%errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   
%stopped_push   --nostringval--
    Dictionary stack:
       --dict:1166/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:95/300(L)--   --dict:17/200(L)--
    Current allocation mode is local
    MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript  9.00: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The error is a postscript error so you will not get an error during latex. You presumably are using pstricks or including an EPS file that is introducing an error. Remove your graphics inclusions and add them back one at a time to see which one breaks.

Comment: `H.S` comes from package `hyperref` with `pdfmark` drivers (`dvips`, `dvipsone`, ...).

Answer (score 5):

In your case, Yap (MiKTeX dvi previewer) has problems in rendering your `.dvi` file.
It may depend on some `.eps` file you are including (as David pointed out) but not necessarily (I've found that sometimes Yap has problems in rendering of fonts, as well).

I've had the same problem in some `.dvi` documents of mine and I've solved changing the `Render Method` to `Dvips`.

To do this in Yap, go to `View` -> `Render Method` and change it from `Pk` to `Dvips`.

If you want to change it globally, go to `View` -> `Options` -> `Display` -> `Default Render Method` and do the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

Also, as pointed out by [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek), you can change the `Backend driver` option of [hyperref](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package to `hypertex` and continue using the [faster and better looking, [1](http://blog.miktex.org/post/2011/02/16/Yap-24-render-method.aspx)] `Pk` renderer method of Yap. However, you will not have the bookmarks on the finished pdf file and links will be looking shady if you use hyperref with this driver.

What I (would) do is the following: unless I need the actual pdf file, I use the `hyperref` package with `hypertex` driver therefore use Yap (dvi editor) with the faster `Pk` renderer. If I do need the pdf then I change the driver of `hyperref` to `ps2pdf` and compile it with `latex(-src-specials) -> dvips(-z -Ppdf) -> ps2pdf` -- which will "pass ‘html’ hyperdvi specials through to the output for eventual distillation into PDF [[2][2]]".

[2]:http:// docs.miktex.org/manual/dvips.html "Usage of dvips"